# fb:login-button scope

Tags: facebook, scope, fbconnect

I have been using the FB:login-button because of its tie in with the registration widget that facebook provides.

Unfortunately, as with most things Facebook related changing it's use to add additional permissions for users as they log in has been less then straight forward.

```
<fb:login-button
registration-url="http://url" perms="publish_actions, publish_checkins, user_location,friends_birthday"></fb:login-button>
```

One would expect this to add the permission friends_birthday.... but on checking the perm with

```
 $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+friends_birthday+FROM+permissions+WHERE+uid=me()'
    . '&' . $access_token;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

a value of 0 is returned, ... 0 for false.

this also does not work when replacing perms by scope (why this was changed... ???)

So.. what is the suggest route to go?
It seems every time i start to change something I find it easier just to rewrite the wheel myself.

Comment: when checking the perms with https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token= the return is as follows: {
   "data": [
      {
         "installed": 1,
         "email": 1
      }
   ]
}

Comment: ok, that is odd... someone just answered this post. when i went to reply there answer had been deleted.

Comment: i have gone ahead and removed the fb:login-button and its associated registration plugin from my site.

Comment: i have now used this logic  FB.getLoginStatus logic, and (redirected --- no added a link ) to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=FBCLIENTID&redirect_uri=URL&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location if they are not authenticated. I will also maintain a link for them to register outside of facebook if they so wish. if i hate facebook, they too probably do./

Comment: facebook.com/ dialog/oauth?client_id=FBCLIENTID&redirect_uri=URL&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location

Comment: I have gone ahead and stopped using the fb:login-button.

Comment: I am instead using the facebook functions getLoginUrl and getLogoutUrl, and will create my own registration after the user authorizes or does not authorize the ap